# How to pass multi select filters with query string using webpart connections

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list-form, query-string

Sharepoint online currently has the function to do a multiselect on filtering of particular column when you are using a list webpart. I was able to use a query string webpart to filter one value, but I was not able to trigger it to filter multiple. Does anyone know the correct syntax for doing this?

I personally tried the following but they didn't work (Filter is the column name denoted here):
`?Filter=a&Filter=b`
`?Filter=a&b`
`?Filter=a,b`
`?Filter=a;b`

EDIT: Some of the answers may have misunderstood intent. The intent is to activate something similar to a true "or" relationship. The list webpart obviously have this as a built in function. I just need the proper syntax to pass in connections properly to activate the filtering mechanism.

[image: Example of what I am trying to achieve]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify the column name with `FilterName` parameter and values with `FilterMultiValue` in your query string.

For example, if you need to filter an issues list to get all issues with priority High and Medium, your URL should be:

```
http://www.example.com/Lists/IssuesList/SampleView.aspx?
FilterName=Priority&FilterMultiValue=High;Medium
```

Comment: Right, but that is without the use or URL query string webpart, which can be a limitation in itself. How can I do this if I want to stick with the out-of-the-box URL query string webpart?

Comment: After further testing, this approach has proven itself that it does not work. It gave an error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904
Correlation ID:c3ae349e-1065-4000-e295-b4b27cccf601" under the heading of the list webpart

Answer (score 1):

What is the column type of the particular column?

If the particular column is the Checkboxes (allow multiple selections), when you filter multiple values on the column by query string(URL) filter web part, it will only filter by the first parameter and skip remaining parameters.

There is a workaround.

We can copy the value from the particular column to a single line of text column.

Edit query string web part, in Advanced Filter Options, select “Combine them into a single value and delimit with , “.

Then configure connection to consumer field on the sing line of text column between query string web part and list web part.

Then use query string in the URL, the result like the below. In my environment, column test1 is the single line of the text.
[image]

For more detailed information, refer to the post below.

[Filter Web Part - option "send all parameters" doesn't work](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230121/filter-web-part-option-send-all-parameters-doesnt-work/230154?noredirect=1#comment246806_230154)

Comment: I tested but it did not work in my environment. The col is a calc col. I resetted the connections after doing what you suggested and it is still filtering only the first item in the query string...